# Hyperref breaks glossary with super- and subscript

Tags: glossaries

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,BCOR10mm,titlepage,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym, toc, nonumberlist,  section=section]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}

\newglossary[mlg]{mathlist}{myi}{myg}{Mathematical Conventions}
\makeglossaries  
                                 % activate glossaries-package
\newglossaryentry{sy:na}{
    name=\ensuremath{n_a},
    description={column vector and scalar (lower case letter)},
    type=mathlist,
    sort=ab}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{}
\printglossary[title=Mathematical Conventions, type=mathlist,style=long,nonumberlist]

\[\gls{sy:na}^2\]

\end{document}
```

My aim is that `$\gls{sy:na}^{2}$` has the same effect as `$n_a^2$`, however it has the effect of `${n_a}^2$`. When I comment out the

```
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
```

line, the superscript works as desired. How can this be circumvented?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I can't reproduce your issue. When I write a small example document around your code I get the correct (i.e., first) output for the `$\gls{sy:na}^{2}$` snippet. Could you add an example document to your code (full document, with documentclass, usepackage statements, begin document, end document, max 20 lines) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Marijn I found that using hyperref leads to the undesired behavior. Any idea how this can be circumvented without refraining from hyperref

Comment: I also found that additional brackets provide a remedy (\gls{sy:na}[^2]). I would however prefer a solution that doesn't require throwing additional brackets at my tex files.

Comment: Do you want to use the standard notation (`^2` or `^{2}`) or would it be acceptable to define an additional command, something like `\glssquare{sy:na}`? In that case you can do some tricks with positioning.

Comment: As stated in my answer, I might just settle with \glsdisablehyper . Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to suppress hyperlinks for glossary entries using

```
\glsdisablehyper
```